# Is it allowed to have cyber(on internet) sex with wife?

Tags: shiism, sex

I know cyber sex with anyone else is utterly prohibited but is it allowed with wife?  I am looking in particular for an answer according to Shi'ite jurisprudence.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**According to Grand Ayatullah Khamenei (as a Marja-al-Taqlid of Shiite),  it won't be prohibited if you do it without using your hands or other things, otherwise it would be Estemna'(الاستمناء), and is not permissible.**

(Note: this is the Fatwa of Ayatullah Khamenei for the question which inquired regarding:is it possible for husband and wife to satisfy(sexually) via phone and Sms. So I reckon your matter would be such the mentioned issue).

Source:

http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa6147

Answer (score 1):

I think, it is better to avoid cyber sex with wife as everything that goes on in the meeting may be getting recorded by the provider of service.  As you know what goes on between husband and wife should be private in Islam. Also, in case if the recordings get leaked to public, it will be very shameful.